# No way to stop sending a welcome email when granting permissions in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, email

When I grant permissions on anything, site, list, etc., in SharePoint 2013 I don't see the ability to opt out of sending an email to the user being added. The only option I see is the group or permission level drop down.

Has it been removed from 2013 or do I not have something set up correctly? For the time being, I removed the outgoing email settings but that is not valid solution.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to have the Send Email unchecked as default?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you add a user / group in SharePoint, you should see "Send an email invitation" check box to control whether or not send the welcome e-mail to the new users.
You could clear that check box and it should fix your problem.

[image]

---

Also, there are some situations when "Send an email invitation" is hidden.
I checked dialog's code-behind by reflector and find that:

Part of InitPage method of AclInv.cs:

```
if (isEmailServerSet)
  {
    if (object.get_IsCompatibilityLevel15Up())
    {
      this.PanelSendEmail.Visible = true;
      this.PanelEmailBody.Visible = true;
      this.txtEmailSubject.Text = SPResource.GetString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "ACLInviteDefaultSubject", (object) this.Web.CurrentUser.Name, (object) this.TargetObjectTitle);
      if (this.CanSendLink)
      {
        this.PanelRequireSignIn.Visible = true;
        this.InitRequireSignInLabel();
      }
      this.peoplePicker.set_VisibleSuggestions(5);
    }
    else
      this.ifsSendEmail.Visible = true;
  }
```

As you can see sharepoint checks "isEmailServerSet" before setting visibility to inviation configuration panels.

As the result, you need to configure outgoing e-mail settings in CA (Central Administration -> System settings -> Configure outgoing e-mail settings) to make invitation configuration visible in "Share" dialog.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I don't have those options. Here is a picture of what I am seeing.

http://i34.tinypic.com/2rmt6s9.png

Comment: I updated my answer. Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks.  I added the outgoing email settings again and recycled to app pool and the options are showing now. Not sure what the issue was...probably user error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using foundation by any chance ? I cant check personally at the moment. But this is just the sort of thing that Microsoft would randomly remove from foundation.

Fyi i get the same as Andrew in Server and 365

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must configure outgoing e-mail settings in Central Admin before you have the option to e-mail out or not when Sharing.